# Possible links of the dreaming and hypnotic state

Tags: eeg, hypnosis

Recently I was asked a question that made me stuck: "how does dreaming states and hypnotic state differ?". What available EEG, fMRI and other means of obtaining data on the brain activity show in such cases?

How much is known about changes of the brain activity when brain moves from wakefulness to sleep?

For now, I only found tiny mentioning of the similarity between the REM state and hypnosis in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnosis) (part about Joe Griffin and Ivan Tyrrell), but there wasn't mentioning of the real similarities like EEG rhythms or brain activity scan data.

The person asking the question mentioned a competent specialist having several decades of practice (I don't know who it is).

He told he heard an intriguing (at least for me) idea from this specialist: "when the person starts to sleep, there is a moment of a high susceptibility to the hypnosis"; I'd like to know a bit more about that: is that right, or maybe there is some misunderstanding? Maybe there are good materials on this particular topic?